# Getting started with solr

Tags: php, solr, pecl

I've struggling a lot trying to get `solr` working. I've read the official docs and tutorials, tried them out but still couldn't figure out how to get started. I took to randomly test out blogs which resulted in crashing of my `ubuntu` OS.

So, I'm framing a question here, outlining every possible doubt of mine and everything I've tried out.

I downloaded the `apache solr 4.3.0` from here: http://lucene.apache.org/solr/
Next, I unzip the file [path: `/home/ps/solr`] and inside there is an `example` directory containing the `schema.xml`, `solrconfig.xml` and other important files.

Next, I choose the official solr php client and installed it. [Link: http://docs.php.net/manual/en/book.solr.php]. It requires a `PECL` extension which I forked from here [https://github.com/lukaszkujawa/php-pecl-solr] as there are some issues with running it with `solr4.x`. The path of `php-pecl-solr` is `home/ps/php-pecl-solr`. I followed this blog (http://systemsarchitect.net/integrate-php-application-with-solr-search-engine/) to install the `PECL` extension.

After all this, I tried writing down a test script (http://dpaste.com/1173282/) as in the blog, and running it: it displayed nothing. The page wasn't opening. The file's path was `var/www/testsolr/index.php`

My doubts:

Why isn't the page opening? What am I doing wrong here?
How to connect the `example` directory of `solr` with this `php-pecl-solr` extension?

I'm just a beginner with these things and would be happy if someone helps me out.

Answer (score 1):

Solr comes with logging code, but it's not enabled by default.

From the example directory, rather than "java -jar start.jar", add a system property on the command line that imports the logging.properties file.  If you launch start.jar from the example directory, use:

```
java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=etc/logging.properties -jar start.jar
```

your log will be in example/logs/solr.log.

I recommend that you not use PHP until you've got solr properly configured and running reliably, after you've been able to import your data and you can do queries from your browser the return the expected results.

I'm new to solr too.  I've been beating my head against it for two weeks, but I'm starting to have some success.

Your log is likely to contain lots of Java exception stack traces.  These are almost always the result of errors in your configuration files, but the log is very unhelpful in that it doesn't tell you what line of which file has the error!  Thus I've had to beg Google for insight, which is sometimes found here at Stackoverflow.

Make sure you have your JDBC connector installed.  It will be a free download for whichever database server your using, but is not bundled with solr.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I've also been banging my head since 1 week. Actually, I'm working on an open-source project which is in `PHP`. So I thought of integrating SolPHP. Also, I thought that the official solr client library would be the best one to use..so went forward with it.

Comment: ptokya, it's best to take little steps when working with complex codebases.  If you set aside the SolPHP wrapper for now, and you have a problem, then you can be certain that problem is not in PHP.

Comment: Could you have a chat with me on SO? I have some minor conceptual doubts, that I wanted to ask. I mean they are small things that I couldn't find answers to anywhere.

Comment: Here's the room I just created: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30147/ptokya-solr

Comment: Not right now, I'm at work and have a pressing project to do.  I could do it when I get home tonight.  Would 9:00 US Pacific Time work for you?  There is some chance I might have to work a little later, in that case it would be 9:45 or so.  Otherwise I'm happy to help.

Comment: Sure. I'll be there at 9:00 (PM? right). (You meant GMT-7.00 Time Zone isn't?)

Comment: Yes, GMT07:00.  See you then!

Comment: I just realized that I'm having some sporadic network trouble where I'm living right now.  If my network is down I may not be able to chat tonight.  But tomorrow is Saturday; I'll be off through the weekend, and should be available online all day long, at a free WiFi spot.

Comment: I'm leaving work right now (5:30 US PDT), but it will take me a while to get home as I have to transfer between two busses.  If my Internet is working, I'll be able to get online right at 9:00.  See you soon.

Comment: Hi, I'm in the room now.  My internet is working fine.  If you can't make it tonight I should be available all day tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to make sure you have Solr running on your server. The simplest way to this is to run `java -jar start.jar` from the `example` directory under `/home/ps/solr`. This will startup Solr using Jetty at the url of `http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr`.

You will need to modify your test.php file and put the full url `http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr` for your `hostname` item in your `$options` array.

Comment: Thanks I managed to get it working. So, every time I fire a HTTP request, I'd make sure that `solr` server is running. How can I do that automatically? I mean, I'm developing modules to enable users to search with my `php` application. And what if they cannot start the `solr` server themselves?

Comment: Typically, you would host Solr in a container, like Tomcat server http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrTomcat or setup Jetty to run as a process on your server. You should be able to find examples of that here on SO on using Google.